# Create a new sheet in a Google Sheets with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to create a new sheet in a Google Sheets with Google Apps Script?

I know it seems obvious but I just want to create a new sheet with a specific name.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Surprisingly I didn't find any clear and quick answer.

So here is my code:

```
function onOpen() {
    var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var yourNewSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Name of your new sheet");

    if (yourNewSheet != null) {
        activeSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(yourNewSheet);
    }

    yourNewSheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
    yourNewSheet.setName("Name of your new sheet");
}
```

Finally, note that this new sheet will be automatically the active one.

Comment: The code is ok but you probably dont want it on onOpen. If you want to create it on user-demand create a menu.

Comment: Yes you're right, this is exactly what I did just after that!

Comment: I was opening a post because every time I create a new sheet using a script the Spreadsheet stops working after a while. Does it happen to you?

Comment: Hum nope sorry, never happened!

Answer (score 22):

I'd recommend [this method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertSheet(String)).

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.insertSheet('My New Sheet');
```

Where 'My New Sheet' is the name you want it to be.

Answer (score 20):

Here is a simple example:

```
var name = (new Date()).toLocaleDateString();
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet(name);
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's the way I did it...

```
var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var newSheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
newSheet.setName("whatever");
```

Comment: How's that better than the earlier answers?

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking at the answers and although they answer the question of how to create a sheet and give it a name, none shows how to make that name variable by passing it as a parameter

This is an **example** of a function **passing a variable** to the createNewSheet function:

(The function that has to be executed is **setNameAndCreateSheet**)

```
function createNewSheet(sheetName){
  // The sheetName parameter has to be passed to the function when it's called
  let activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let newSheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
  newSheet.setName(sheetName); // We sheet will be called as the string of the parameter
}

function setNameAndCreateSheet(){
  // This will get the email of the user executing the script
  const userEmail = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();

  // This will get the current date
  const date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "dd/MM/yyyy");

  // We are making the string that will be passed to the createNewSheet function
  const sheetName = date + " - " + userEmail;
  // sheetName will return something like: "04/11/2021 - youremail@gmail.com"

  // This will execute the function that creates the sheet, and the name will be settled to the parameter passed (sheetName)
  createNewSheet(sheetName);
}
```

In this example, the parameter passed to the createNewSheet function is the concatenation of these two strings (date - useremail), but it could be anything.

Answer (score 1):

This function does that with more options, where you can select:

1. The new sheet name
2. Add the sheet to which spreadsheet
3. After (or before) which sheet (index or name)
4. Choose to add a counter or delete if the new name is already used before.

---

```
function addSheet(shName, ss, aftr, bfr, delMode) {
  var sh = null;
  // Define the optional argument ss (Spreadsheet) if missing
  if (ss == null) ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // If no new name is given, use "Sheet" and deactivate delete mode
  if (shName == null) {
    delMode = null
    shName = "Sheet"
  }
  
  if (delMode == null) {
    // If delete mode is inactive, use a counter if the name already exists (like "Sheet (2)")
    var n = 1;
    var nShName = shName;
    while (ss.getSheetByName(nShName) != null) {
      n += 1;
      nShName = shName + ' (' + n + ')';
    }
    shName = nShName;
  } else {
    // otherwise, delete on sight!
    sh = ss.getSheetByName(shName);
    if (sh != null) ss.deleteSheet(sh);
  }
  // Where to add the new sheet:
  if (aftr == null) {
    if (bfr == null) {
      // If both after and before arguments are missing, add the new sheet to the end of sheets list.
      n = ss.getSheets().length;
      // Uncomment the next one if you want it to be added after the active sheet
      // n = ss.getActiveSheet().getIndex();
    } else if (typeof(bfr) == 'string') {
      // If before argument was given as string (Sheet name), try to find it.
      n = getSheetOrder(bfr) - 1
    } else {
      // otherwise use the given number
      n = bfr - 1
    }
  } else if (typeof(aftr) == 'string') {
    // If after argument was give as string (Sheet name), try to find it.
    n = getSheetOrder(aftr);
  } else {
    // otherwise use the given number
    n = aftr;
  }
  // Note: if both after and bfr are given, bfr is ignored.

  // Fix the case where only before argument is gevin as a string,but no sheet with that name is found
  if (n < 0) n = 0;
  // Fix the case where the numbers given were too high
  if (n > ss.getSheets().length) n = ss.getSheets().length;
  // Do the action!
  return ss.insertSheet(shName, n);
}
```

---

```
function getSheetOrder(shName, ss) {
  // returns 0 if sheet is missing, or the sheet index if found.
  if (ss == null) ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName(shName);
  if (sh == null) return 0;
  return sh.getIndex();
}
```

---

Tests:

`addSheet()` adds a sheet named "Sheet" (or "Sheet (2)", "Sheet (3)",...) to the end of the file (or after the active sheet if you edit the code)

`addSheet("My Sheet", null, 3, null, 1)` adds a sheet names "My Sheet" after the third sheet in the active spreadsheet, and deletes the old sheet with the same name if found.