# Store result to Google Spreadsheet from script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code that outputs the data to the log file. How can I make this script to send the output to a spreadsheet instead of the log and whenever the script is run add an additional sheet in the spreadhsheet with the data. The sheet should be named based on the date and time the script ran.

```
function listAllUsers() {
  var pageToken, page;
  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
      domain: 'mydomain.com',
      orderBy: 'givenName',

      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    var users = page.users;
    if (users) {
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
        Logger.log('%s (%s)', user.name.fullName, user.primaryEmail);
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No users found.');
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
}
```

Regards

Comment: Your question contains the full code from an [example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory). The functions you need to perform the additional operations you're interested in are available in the [Spreadsheet Service documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/). Look for Spreadsheet.insertSheet(sheetName) and Sheet.appendRow(rowContents).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a simpler implementation, see comments in code :

```
function listAllUsers() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.insertSheet(0);// create new sheet in first position
  sh.setName(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),'MMM-dd-yyy@hh:mm:ss'));
  var data = [];// array to store values
  data.push(['user fullName', 'user primary Emai']);// store headers
  var pageToken, page;
  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
      domain: 'mydomain.com',
      orderBy: 'givenName',

      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    var users = page.users;
    if (users) {
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
        Logger.log('%s (%s)', user.name.fullName, user.primaryEmail);
        data.push([user.name.fullName, user.primaryEmail]);//store in an array of arrays (one for each row)
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No users found.');
      data.push(['No users found.','--']);
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  sh.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This seems to perfectly address my issue.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example of how to put data onto a sheet:

```
//now write this data to the Detail spreadsheet
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var destSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Detail");
var destSheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Summary");

//Clear values before pasting array data
destSheet.getRange(2, 1, 300, 20).clear();
destSheet2.getRange(2, 1, 50, 20).clear();

var numFormat = "0.00%"

//set spreadsheet values and apply conditional formatting.

for (var i = 2; i < (arrEmpCapDet.length + 2); i++) {
  destSheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, arrEmpCapDet[i-2].length).setValues(new Array(arrEmpCapDet[i-2]));
  destSheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, arrEmpCapDet[i-2].length).setNumberFormat(numFormat);
} 

for (var i = 2; i < (arrEmpCapSum.length + 2); i++) {
  destSheet2.getRange(i, 1, 1, arrEmpCapSum[i-2].length).setValues(new Array(arrEmpCapSum[i-2]));
  destSheet2.getRange(i, 1, 1, arrEmpCapSum[i-2].length).setNumberFormat(numFormat);
  //for each item in the row, check if the value is above 100% or below 50%, then change color.
  for (var p = 2; p < 16; p++) {
    var tmpValue = destSheet2.getRange(i, p).getValue();
    //Logger.log(tmpValue);
    if (tmpValue > 1.0)  {
     destSheet2.getRange(i, p).setBackground('red');
    }
    if (tmpValue < 0.5)  {
     destSheet2.getRange(i, p).setBackground('green');
    }
  }
}
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898501/create-a-new-sheet-in-a-google-spreadsheet-with-google-apps-script) for info on creating a new sheet.

Comment: really don't see how this code is related to the question... can you explain what you had in mind ? are you sure you posted on the right thread ?